# Add vertical line to a seqIplot

Tags: r, seq, traminer

I am plotting a sequence object in tramineR using seqIplot(). I want to add a vertical line to the plot, something similar to abline(v=x) however I do not know how to reference the x-axis in such a context. A quick scan in the tramineR documentation was not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of the x-axis are simply the numbers of time units from the left.

However, to apply `abline` you need to suppress the legend. Otherwise, the plot is a multiple graph obtained with `layout` that does not support `abline`.

I illustrate using the `mvad` data from `TraMineR`.

library(TraMineR)

```
data(mvad)
mvad.lab <- c("employment", "further education", "higher education",
              "joblessness", "school", "training")
mvad.shortlab <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[, 17:86], states = mvad.shortlab,
                   labels = mvad.lab, weights = mvad$weight, xtstep = 6)
```

Vertical line at the 12th month

```
seqiplot(mvad.seq, border=NA, with.legend=FALSE)
abline(v=12)
```

[image]